# Hostname in postfix changing automatically during installation

Tags: 17.04, postfix, hostname, mail-server, mailutils

I was installing **tlp** for ubuntu. During installation a dialog box for changing postfix configuration had popped up, and I went with the default options, setting the **hostname** as *Jayant*.

Now, when I try to install or uninstall any package, an error pops up as

`Errors were encountered while processing: postfix, mailutils sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an exit code(1)`

In the message, it was written as `Setting myhostname=Jayant..name in /etc/postfix`, which is causing the problem of **bad parameter value**

I tried to update the value of myhostname variable in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and changed it from *Jayant..name* to *Jayant*

Then, I executed the command `service postfix reload` to restart the postfix.

However,when again trying to install any package, the same error pops up and my change to the file is reverted back. And when I now see the file `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, once again the **myhostname** variable holds *Jayant..name* value.

So how do I solve this problem? Is there anywhere else I need to update **myhostname** variable value?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue so just uninstall postfix and reinstall with no configuration instead of choosing local host and then once it has finished installing, manually change cofigurations in /etc/postfix/main.cf.